# pulling sql column names for a table

Tags: sql

Is there a way to write a query in sql that will return the column names for the table?

e.g. if table Foo had columns bar and baz, this query would return 2 rows with "bar" and "baz" in them.

Comment: The implementation varies by database platform. Please update your question with your db platform.

Comment: It's possible, but it will vary, depending on what database you're using. Are you on Oracle? MSSQL? DB2? MSAccess? Paradox? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way that will work on SQL Server, PostgreSQL and MySQL (might work on others too, will not work on Oracle)

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) tables for this. Not all databases implement them however. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Foo;
```